# Flask_wtf - validate_on_submit() error on page load

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Flask_wtf's validate_on_submit() is never `True` on visiting the page for the first time, so it always flashes the `else` part's (code below) Error message which is always an empty dict.

But the form validation and submission are working properly - the success flash message can be seen on a valid post. And the Error flash doesn't disappear after a valid submission.

Reproducible code:

```
# necessary import stmts & other stuff

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    sub = StringField(validators=[DataRequired("Choose the title")])
    body = TextAreaField(validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=20)])
    subm = SubmitField('Submit')

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my key'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    fo = MyForm() 
    flash('Submitted:'+str(fo.is_submitted())) # False on first time visit
    #flash('After Validate:'+str(fo.validate())) 
    
    if fo.validate_on_submit():
        ex = mytable(bodys = fo.body.data, subs = fo.sub.data)
        # DB session add & commit stmt here
        flash('Submitted','success')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        flash('After val Errors:'+str(fo.errors))
    return render_template('index.html',form=fo)
```

If I un-comment fo.validate()...it flashes `csrf_token': ['The CSRF token is missing.']` and the other data required error msgs but as shown below the html template has `form.hidden_tag()`. Also used `{{ form.csrf_token }}` instead of hidden_tag()...no success.

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.sub }}
    {{ form.body }}
    {{ form.subm }}
    </form>
```

Please help to get rid of the validation error on page load, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So on initial get you don't need to validate your form because there's no data yet, only do it when it's actually posted, like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if fo.validate_on_submit():
        # DB session add & commit stmt here
        flash('Submitted', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        flash('After val Errors:' + str(fo.errors))
```

Comment: but `validate_on_submit()` will check if a request is GET or POST right?... we dont have to check for it, do we?

Comment: It will check if it's submitted AND if it's valid. If either is false you get a false as a result. So you do need that check.

Comment: @Naveen alternatively you can replace your else statement with elif fo.is_submitted() if you like that way better